# Custom Arguments to User Command

Tags: neovim, user-commands

I am trying to create a command that runs a function, however, I can seem to get custom arguments that are autocompleted when pressing `Tab`. How would it be possible to set these arguments?

The current command looks like this...

```
command! -nargs=? UserCommand :lua require('my-plugin').function(<f-args>)
```

and I want there to be completion for 5, single worded, arguments that will be passed on to a Lua function.

5 Possible Arguments:

1. `terminal`
2. `quickfix`
3. `internal`
4. `bang`
5. `float`

I've taken a look at [telescope.nvim's](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/blob/master/plugin/telescope.vim#L98-L126) way of doing this but it seems to do a lot more than just add completion for a few strings.

Comment: Are you looking for `-complete`? See [`:help :command-completion`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion) for details

Comment: This doesn't exactly help too much. Could you perhaps provide some code that's not already in the help pages?

Comment: In that case, you should [edit] your question to tell us more of what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried so far and how it isn't working... As is, your question is too open ended, it's hard to figure out exactly what it is that you want...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the question to be a little more specific and hopefully less open-ended.

Comment: Yes, but "completion for 5, single worded, arguments that will be passed on to a Lua function" still doesn't tell me what those are... Are they file names? Numbers? Enum items from one (or 5?) fixed list(s)? It looks like what you want is custom completion, which you can get with `custom,{func}` and `customlist,{func}`, where you can write a Vimscript (or maybe a small stub to Lua?) function to implement the completion selection... See `:help :command-completion-customlist` for more details.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've included the 5 arguments that should be auto-completed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I just posted an answer, hopefully that's what you're looking for (or close enough that you can adapt it for what you're after...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-complete=...` flag while defining a user-command to program how tab completion should work when the command is used. See [`:help :command-completion`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion) for more details about that flag.

The `-complete=...` flag has many built-in options to complete common objects in the Vim world, such as file names in paths, buffers, Ex commands, functions, etc.

In your case, it looks like none of those will do the job, so you can use the *custom* completion, by providing Vim with a function that will return the available options. See [`:help :command-completion-custom`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-completion-custom) for more details about custom completion.

It's not too hard to write a custom completion function, particularly one that will select options from a fixed list. If you use `-complete=custom,...` then Vim will filter the options for you using the characters already typed by the user as a prefix.

For example:

```
function! UserCommandCompletion(_, _, _)
  let valid_args = ['terminal', 'quickfix', 'internal', 'bang', 'float']
  return join(valid_args, "\n")
endfunction
```

You can use it in your user command definition with:

```
command! -nargs=? -complete=custom,UserCommandCompletion UserCommand :lua require('my-plugin').function(<f-args>)
```

You can then use it with `:UserCommand te<Tab>` will complete it to `terminal`. Just `:UserCommand <Tab>` will offer you the five options (in the order they're defined.)

---

You can also use the `-complete=customlost,...` mode. On one hand, in that case returns a list, so you don't need to join it into a muli-line string. On the other, there's a slightly tricky part of filtering the list based on the characters already typed by the user. With some string manipulation, you can get it done.

For example:

```
function! UserCommandListCompletion(lead, cmd, cursor)
  let valid_args = ['terminal', 'quickfix', 'internal', 'bang', 'float']
  let l = len(a:lead) - 1
  if l >= 0
    let filtered_args = copy(valid_args)
    call filter(filtered_args, {_, v -> v[:l] ==# a:lead})
    if !empty(filtered_args)
      return filtered_args
    endif
  endif
  return valid_args
endfunction

command! -nargs=? -complete=customlost,UserCommandListCompletion UserCommand :lua require('my-plugin').function(<f-args>)
```

This function will try to find the elements of the list starting with the passed `lead`. (If the lead is empty, or no elements are found, it just returns the full list, so you get all valid options for completion.)

One small advantage of `customlist` is that you're free to return an option that doesn't start with the same prefix altogether. For example, in the implementation above, you'll get the full list of all valid options if the word being typed is not a valid prefix to at least one of the acceptable options. With the `-complete=custom,...` implementation a word that's not a valid prefix will simply not yield any completion when Tab is pressed.

Comment: An alternative might be to use `custom` and always return `join("\n", [the list])`, letting vim's engine do the filtering

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah that's definitely better! I wonder why the two options work differently from each other, didn't spot that in the docs either... I'll update the answer to mention that (a little bit later this evening.)

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much for the amazing answer.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this directly in lua in neovim? Without any vimscript?